# Firebase Admin SDK sendToTopic not working

Tags: android, ios, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm deploying a mobile application (for Android and iOS) through which the admin can send alert to users registered to a specific topic. To do that I'm using Realtime Database to store alerts and cloud functions to send notifications to topic.

I've the following cloud function deployed:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNewAlertNotification = functions.database.ref('/alerts').onWrite(event => {
    const getValuePromise = admin.database()
        .ref('alerts')
        .orderByKey()
        .limitToLast(1)
        .once('value');

    return getValuePromise.then(snapshot => {
        const { text, topics, author } = snapshotToArray(snapshot)[0];

        const payload = {
            data: {
                title: 'Avviso',
                body: text,
                icon: 'ic_stat_notify',
                sound: 'default',
                color: '#F3E03B',
                tag: 'alerts',
                ticker: 'Nuovo avviso',
                subtitle: 'Avvisi',
                author: JSON.stringify(author)
            }
        };

        const options = {
            priority: 'high',
            timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24 * 2, // 48 hours
            collapseKey: 'it.bmsoftware.caliup'
            // contentAvailable: true
        };

        if (topics.length > 1) {
            let condition = '';
            topics.forEach((topic, index) => {
                condition += `'${topic}' in topics`

                if (index < topics.length - 1) {
                    condition += ' || '
                }
            });
            console.log(`Sending alert to condition '${condition}' -> ${JSON.stringify(payload)}`);
            return admin.messaging().sendToCondition(condition, payload, options);
        } else if (topics.length === 1) {
            let topic = topics[0];
            console.log(`Sending alert to topic '${topic}' -> ${JSON.stringify(payload)}`);
            return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload, options);
        } else {
            console.log(`No topics found`);
        }
    });
});

const snapshotToArray = (snapshot) => {
    let result = []
    if (!snapshot || !snapshot.val())
        return result

    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        let item = childSnapshot.val()
        item.key = childSnapshot.key
        result.push(item)
    })

    return result
}
```

When I insert a new message on the realtime database, the above function fetch that message correctly and in the log section (on the firebase console) I see the correct custom log and a log that says `status 'ok'`.

Despite this, no notification arrives on devices. If I test the same topic from firebase console directly it works fine so devices are properly registered.

Is there something wrong with the cloud function that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should uncomment `// contentAvailable: true` if you are sending only `data` payload, at least for iOS. That way you'll be able to show and trigger the notification yourself on the app code. If you want the notification to pop up without having to process the data payload, you should pass a `notification` object on payload.

Notification is limited to these fields tho: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.NotificationMessagePayload